# Outlook Add-In Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync() Separate user input from forward or respond content

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way to only get the user's input from an email(item body) when the user responds to an email or does a forward?

If I use `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync()` with text coercion is not possible and with HTML coercion I'm not sure if it would reliable in time since it will depend on guessing classes, structure or attributes to parse and extract the content and maybe these classes/structure will change in Outlook updates.

Comment: This is asking about the compose secnario? (when a user replies to an email) There isn't a way to do this via the office.js apis. As you mentioned, the best that is possible is to get the HTML coercion and decipher the bookmarks/indicators there, but this could change per Outlook client/version.